# Unable to translate previous moderator actions on flag dashboard page

Tags: bug, status-review, flags, moderator-tools, localization

There's no string to translate for previous moderator actions on the flag dashboard page - in particular, "[Added Comment](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Added%20Comment)":

> [image]

But it seems that all other mod actions are affected.

Comment: Based on some testing, some of the possible strings that can show up here include "Added Comment", "Post Deleted", "Annotation", "Suspend", "Edit Tags", and "LeftClosed". (And I can confirm that at the least, "Added Comment" and "Post Closed" aren't being translated on the international sites.)

Comment: It looks like there might be 2 separate issues here: the string "Added Comment" isn't set as translatable, and the translations for these strings aren't being displayed on the flag dashboard page even if the string has been translated in Traducir (e.g. "[Post Closed](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Post%20Closed)" on SOes).